# C3.js graph not able to get back the graph when we click twice on a legend

Tags: javascript, html

By using the following code I could generate a graph in Ionic app(issue is only on mobile). But when I click on a legend; that particular section is hiding. And when I re-click second time on the same legend, not able to get entire graph.  Only that particular section is visible and rest all are getting hidden, that means not showing clearly. Visibility is dim.

Let me explain clearly.  Suppose, if we click on legend 'a' (small square violet in color), that section is getting hidden. And the rest 'b','c','d' are visible clearly in graph. When we re-click on 'a' again, then 'b','c', & 'd' are visible in dim.  I want to show all the legends or sections 'a','b','c' and 'd' clearly when we re-click on 'a'.

```js
    
    var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#graph',
        data: {
           columns: [
                     ["a",25],
                     ["b",53],
                     ["c",35],
                     ["d",52]
                    ],
           type:'pie',
           colors:{ 
                     a: '#800080', 
                     b: '#2a6496',
                     c: 'rgb(214, 39, 40)',
                     d:'#000000'
                  },
                }});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"  charset="utf-8"></script>
    <div id="graph" style="height:200px;width:200px"></div>
```

Comment: But it's just emulating what happens when you hover on a label without clicking anything.  Isn't that what it's supposed to do?  If you don't like the behavior after clicking to make a slice visible, just disable the fade out of other slices on hover entirely.

Comment: Joseph, I'm just talking about the legend 'a','b','c' and 'd' below the graph.

Comment: Joseph, I'm just talking about the legend 'a','b','c' and 'd' below the graph. When we click on 'd' that corresponding slice in pie gets hidden.  When we re-click on the same 'd' again, it will show the slice 'd'(black in color) and 'a','b' and 'c' in dim.  That is fine. But when we release our control from graph completely, all the slices 'a', 'b' ,'c' and 'd' are visible again clearly.  But in the mobile(IONIC APP) it is not happening.  To get all the slices/sections of the graph clearly again, we need to close the APP or re-open it again.  But in the web it is working fine.